# Metodo de inserción duda de como desarrollarlo en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy buscando ganar algo de lógica haciendo un proyectito super sencillo ya lo tenía todo terminado pero me surgió un último problema que es ordenar el arreglo. Me gustaría usar .sort() y asunto solucionado, pero como les digo quiero entender las bases.

```
let num = 0;
let arr = [];
let val = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  let ask = window.prompt("write seven numbers in disorder");//num ask 7 numbers
  num = parseInt(ask); //convierto los valores a números
  arr.push(num); //introduzco los valores en arr a través de push

  let val = num[i + 1]; //segundo valor como clave

  if(val < num[i - 1]) //si el segundo valor es menor a la izquierda {
    num[i-1] = val; //value pasara a la izquierda }
}

for(let j = 0;  j < arr.length; j++) {
  if(val[j] < num[j - 1]) {
    num[j - 1] = val;
    num[j] = num[j + 1];
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

No logro entender el metodo de la inserción, siempre se reemplaza el numero actual con los numeros a la izquierda, pero cuando lo implemento simplemente sale una mezcolanza y creo que es porque no sé como implementarlo, alguien me lo podría explicar o dar una ayuda donde encontrar una forma más simplificada de entenderlo. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Para los ordenamientos siempre es bueno implementar una función `swap` que intercambia de posición 2 elementos de un `array`, de esta manera:

```
function swap(n,m){
  const a = arr[n];
  arr[n] = arr[m];
  arr[m] = a;
}
```

Tu tienes un caso muy particular, vas ingresando elementos y los ordenas. Es decir **siempre** tu array está ordenado, por lo que un algoritmo simple es:

- Ingresar el elemento al final
- Compararlo con el anterior

  - Si es menor, intercambiarlo de posición con él y seguir a la siguiente iteración para compararlo nuevamente con el anterior
  - Si es mayor igual, detenemos la comparación (`break`) porque el array está ordenado, no es necesario segur comparando

Es decir:

1ra Iteración

```
         _
        | |
1,2,3,6,8,5 -> swap -> 1,2,3,6,5,8
```

2da Iteración

```
       _
      | |
1,2,3,6,5,8 -> swap -> 1,2,3,5,6,8
```

3a Iteración

```
     _
    | |
1,2,3,5,6,8 -> es mayor, detenemos
```

```js
let num = 0;
let arr = [];
let val = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
let ask = window.prompt("write seven numbers in disorder");//num ask 7 numbers
  num = parseInt(ask); //convierto los valores a números
  arr.push(num); //introduzco los valores en arr a través de push

  if(i==0) continue; //para el primero caso

  for(let j = arr.length-2;  j >=0; j--) { //comenzamos desde el penultimo a comparar contra el último ingresado
      if(num>=arr[j]) {
         break;
      }
      swap(j,j+1);
  }

}

function swap(n,m){
  const a = arr[n];
  arr[n] = arr[m];
  arr[m] = a;
}

  console.log(arr);
```